# Returning list via ajax to populate table - values are underfined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm learning SignalR im following this [database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr](http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency) 
When I return the list back all my column values are underfined

below is how my view is currently constructed

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    // Proxy created on the fly
    var job = $.connection.myHub;

    // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
    job.client.displayStatus = function () {
        getData();
    };

    // Start the connection
      $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      getData();
    });
});

function getData() {
    var $tbl = $('#tblJobInfo');
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Get", "Home")',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $tbl.empty();
                $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>lname</th><th>phone</th></tr>');
                var rows = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].id + '</td><td>' + data[i].fname + '</td><td>' + data[i].lname + '</td><td>' + data[i].phone + '</td></tr>');
                }
                $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div>
    <table id="tblJobInfo" style="text-align:center;margin-left:10px"></table>
</div>
```

When my page loads it calls this method

```
public List<JobInfo> Get()
{
    var det = objRepo.GetData();

    return det;
}
```

I've placed a breakpoint on return det; and I can see the relevant values inside the list, how ever when trying to build the table as mentioned previously the column values are "underfined"

this is the JobInfo class

```
public class JobInfo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Many thanks

**update**

Below is what is written in the browser when doing console.log(data);

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KnockOutjsTutorial.Models.JobInfo]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    getData();
});
```

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Since `start()` is async, the call to `getData()` in your current code is executing before `start()` has completed. By placing your code in `done`, you can be confident that SignalR has created a connection at that point.

EDIT:

I think the problem is the controller method. Does it looks something like this?

```
public ActionResult Get()
{
    var data = Get(); // Which returns List<JonInfo>.

    return Json(data);
}
```

You need to return that list of jobs as JSON.

EDIT:

Based on the conversation we had in the chat room, the problem was caused by a call to:

`Clients.All.displayStatus()`

and having multiple tabs open. So changing the code to

`Clients.Caller.displayStatus()`

should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the additional information Ive replaced my original snippet with the one you provided, yet my table still has "underfined" values, even though I actually see the correct values when debugging

Comment: To confrim, the variable `data` in the `success` function does contain values?

Comment: yes, I put a break point on return det; and expand the variable and I can see 1 row with 4 columns of data which are mt details id = 1, fname = scott, lname = test, phone = 07777777777

Comment: this is a bit weird aswell, I have 1 row in data, yet when I put an alert just before the for loop it alerts saying the data.length = 68 ?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(data)` as the first line of the `sucess`? What does that show, can you post that in your question?

Comment: Can you show the code for your controller's action method named `Get`? I strongly suspect you are not passing the data back as JSON. That's my hunch.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49846/discussion-between-jason-evans-and-scott-atkinson)